# Ruby calculate percentages of array objects

Tags: ruby, arrays, count

I have an array:

`array = ["one", "two", "two", "three"]`

Now I need to create a separate array with the percentages of each of these items out of the total array.

Final result:

`percentages_array = [".25",".50",".50",".25]`

I can do something like this:

```
percentage_array = []
one_count = array.grep(/one/).count
two_count = array.grep(/two/).count

array.each do |x|
  if x == "one"
    percentage_array << one_count.to_f / array.count.to_f
  elsif x == "two"
    ....
  end
end
```

But how can I write it a little more concise and dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the group by function:

```
 my_array = ["one", "two", "two", "three"]
 percentages = Hash[array.group_by{|x|x}.map{|x, y| [x, 1.0*y.size/my_array.size]}]
 p  percentages #=> {"one"=>0.25, "two"=>0.5, "three"=>0.25}
 final = array.map{|x| percentages[x]}
 p final #=> [0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25]
```

Alternative 2 without group_by:

```
array, result = ["one", "two", "two", "three"], Hash.new
array.uniq.each  do |number|
  result[number] = array.count(number)
end
p array.map{|x| 1.0*result[x]/array.size}  #=> [0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25]
```

Comment: @SirDarius, it is available in 1.9 and 2.0 at least. Please check the docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html

Comment: yes, for some reason I did check them, and didn't _see_ the method, nevermind my comment !

Comment: `Enumerable#group_by` is even since version [1.8.6](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, but you find it more useful to just use the hash `h`:

```
array = ["one", "two", "two", "three"]

fac = 1.0/array.size
h = array.reduce(Hash.new(0)) {|h, e| h[e] += fac; h}
  # => {"one"=>0.25, "two"=>0.5, "three"=>0.25} 
array.map {|e| h[e]} #  => [0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25]
```

Edit: as @Victor suggested, the last two lines could be replaced with:

```
array.reduce(Hash.new(0)) {|h, e| h[e] += fac; h}.values_at(*array)
```

Thanks, Victor, a definite improvement (unless use of the hash is sufficient).

Comment: `h.values_at(*array)` as the last line looks arguably better and can be chained to the previous line

Answer (score 0):

```
percentage_array = []
percents = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
array.each do |x|
  number = find_number(x)
  percents[number] += 1.0 / array.length
end
array.each do |x|
  percentage_array.append(percents[find_number(x)].to_s)
end

def find_number(x)
  if x == "two"
    return 1
  elsif x == "three"
    return 2
  end
  return 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized way to do this:

```
def percents(arr)
  map = Hash.new(0)
  arr.each { |val| map[val] += 1 }
  arr.map { |val| (map[val]/arr.count.to_f).to_s }
end

p percents(["one", "two", "two", "three"]) # prints ["0.25", "0.5", "0.5", "0.25"]
```